# Problems migrating from one vps to a new one XAMPP Linux

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xampp

Now i'm getting this error when i try to go to "domain.com/admin"

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

Also i should be able to use phpmyadmin using domain like `"domain.com/phpmyadmin"`, but is not working with the new IP.

What i do:

- Install same Xampp and configure security.

  `sshadmin@ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01:~$ sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.0.8-0-installer.run
  [sudo] password for sshadmin:
  sshadmin@ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01:~$ sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.0.8-0-installer.run
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Welcome to the XAMPP Setup Wizard.
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Select the components you want to install; clear the components you do not want
  to install. Click Next when you are ready to continue.
  XAMPP Core Files : Y (Cannot be edited)
  XAMPP Developer Files [Y/n] :y
  Is the selection above correct? [Y/n]: y
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Installation Directory
  XAMPP will be installed to /opt/lampp
  Press [Enter] to continue:
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Setup is now ready to begin installing XAMPP on your computer.
  Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: y
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Please wait while Setup installs XAMPP on your computer.
  Installing
  0% ______________ 50% ______________ 100%
  #########################################
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Setup has finished installing XAMPP on your computer.
  sshadmin@ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
  Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.0.8-0...
  XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
  XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
  XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
  sshadmin@ubuntu-512mb-nyc3-01:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp security
  XAMPP:  Quick security check...
  XAMPP:  Your XAMPP pages are NOT secured by a password.
  XAMPP: Do you want to set a password? [yes] yes
  XAMPP: Password:
  XAMPP: Password (again):
  /opt/lampp/share/xampp/checkapache: line 41: /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/.htaccess: No such file or directory
  cp: cannot stat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/.htaccess': No such file or directory
  cp: cannot stat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/.htaccess': No such file or directory
  chmod: cannot access '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/.htaccess': No such file or directory
  chmod: cannot access '/opt/lampp/htdocs/webalizer/.htaccess': No such file or directory
  chmod: cannot access '/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/.htaccess': No such file or directory
  XAMPP:  Password protection active. Please use 'xampp' as user name!
  XAMPP:  MySQL is accessable via network.
  XAMPP: Normaly that's not recommended. Do you want me to turn it off? [yes] yes
  XAMPP:  Turned off.
  XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
  XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
  XAMPP:  The MySQL/phpMyAdmin user pma has no password set!!!
  XAMPP: Do you want to set a password? [yes] yes
  XAMPP: Password:
  XAMPP: Password (again):
  XAMPP:  Setting new MySQL pma password.
  XAMPP:  Setting phpMyAdmin's pma password to the new one.
  XAMPP:  MySQL has no root passwort set!!!
  XAMPP: Do you want to set a password? [yes] yes
  XAMPP:  Write the password somewhere down to make sure you won't forget it!!!
  XAMPP: Password:
  XAMPP: Password (again):
  XAMPP:  Setting new MySQL root password.
  XAMPP:  Change phpMyAdmin's authentication method.
  XAMPP:  The FTP password for user 'daemon' is still set to 'xampp'.
  XAMPP: Do you want to change the password? [yes] yes
  XAMPP: Password:
  XAMPP: Password (again):
  XAMPP: Reload ProFTPD...ok.
  XAMPP:  Done.`
- Copy with WinSCP the files from the old VPS to the new.

  `/opt/lampp/domain.com`
- Edit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf

  `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
- Edit /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

  `<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/domain.com/"
      ServerName dotaskapp.com
  </VirtualHost>`
- Edit /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf

  `<Directory "/opt/lampp/domain.com/">>
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny    allow from all  Require all granted
      ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var 
  </Directory>
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
      AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
      Require local
      Require ip myip
      ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var 
  </Directory>
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/phpsqliteadmin">
      AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
      Require local
      Require ip myip
      ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var 
  </Directory>`
- In browser: http://vpsIp/phpmyadmin/ and import data base.
- Edit /etc/hosts

  `127.0.0.1 domain.com`
- Restart xampp.

  `/opt/lampp/lampp restart`

Change the domain nameservers IP to the new VPS IP.

Comment: Not working **HOW**? all of the above is useless until you can explain WHAT isn't working?

Comment: 1. This is more of an operations related question rather thanswdevelopment related. Sysadmins would be in alot better position to provide an answer. 2. Without an actual error message, we can only guess what may have gone wrong.

Comment: it depends to the error if your main domain works but you have problem with sub urls like `/admin` and if you get 404 it can be **apache rewrite module**.
if it's 403 it can be files and folders permissions (also depends on project)

Comment: Now i'm getting an error, the problem was the nameservers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix domain problem i change the nameservers, because my new VPS only accept their own nameservers.

The problem with "Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.".

Was fixed adding a new user with the same credentials in phpMyAdmin.